# remove a substring from a string in javascript with multiple scenarios

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a string `hello` and I want it to subtract from the strings.

- `hello_my_good_world`
- `my_hello_good_world`
- `my_good_hello_world`

And the output from above strings must be like following respectively.

- `my_good_world`
- `my_good_world`
- `my_good_world`

Please note that how underscore `_` got removed too. If string `hello` is at the start then it should remove underscore ahead, If it is in the middle then it should remove either next or previous underscore. So I don't have duplicate underscores. And if substring is at the end then it should remove previous underscore. I tried using JS `replace` method but I can remove only substring. Haven't figured out how to handle duplicate underscores to eliminate them too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `.replace(/hello_|_hello/g,'')`

```js
console.log("hello_my_good_world".replace(/hello_|_hello/g,''))
console.log("my_hello_good_world".replace(/hello_|_hello/g,''))
console.log("my_good_hello_world".replace(/hello_|_hello/g,''))
```

Comment: Thanks Bro.. Worked perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do multiple replacements.

```js
const tests = [
    'hello_my_good_world',
    'my_hello_good_world',
    'my_good_hello_world',
]

const replaced = tests.map(s => {
    const replacement = s
        .replace('hello', '')   // eliminate 'hello'
        .replace('__', '_')     // eliminate double underscore
        .replace(/^_/g, '')     // eliminate leading underscore
        .replace(/_$/g, '')     // eliminate trailing underscore
    
    return replacement;
});

console.log({
    replaced,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to split the string on `_`, filter out `"hello"`, and rejoin with `_`:

```js
console.log("hello_my_good_world".split("_").filter(s => s !== "hello").join("_"))
console.log("my_hello_good_world".split("_").filter(s => s !== "hello").join("_"))
console.log("my_good_hello_world".split("_").filter(s => s !== "hello").join("_"))
```